# It is ok to have a class that controls other classes?

Tags: c++, architecture

Lets say in my project i have the classes Interface, Network, Database and Mediator.

For example, when I click "Send" on Interface, it will talk to Mediator and call a function "Send" which will then talk to the Network class and the Database class to send something and save it or whatever.

If i remove the Mediator class, from Interface I will have to talk to two separate classes, Network and Database independently.

The thing is that I think having a Mediator class breaks the Single Responsibility Principle, it a class who stores the 3 other classes (Interface, Database and Network) and manages all the interactions between them, it's not a big class, but there is a better way? Should I refer independently in each class to every other class I need? Thanks

Comment: How does it break the SRP ? If it's purpose is to manage the interactions between them and does only that, this doesn't break the principle

Comment: Saying that you just made say "fu**", i was getting wrong the theory about the SRP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single Responsibility Principle means that an entity shouldn't perform actions that are beyond what is its purpose. You state the purpose of your Mediator class, and as long as you stick to its purpose you are not breaking the principle.

Here I give you an example on how you would have broken the principle instead. Say you need a new database related functionality. If, for whatever reason, you end up implementing that functionality in Mediator class, in that case you would be violating the principle.